# When to use a ported (instead of an international) CC 3.0 license?

Tags: creative-commons

If I want to license my work under a Creative Commons 3.0 license, I could use:

- the international/unported version
- the version ported for my jurisdiction

(For example, in case of CC BY-SA 3.0: [CC BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) vs. [CC BY-SA 3.0 DE](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/de/))

**What would be possible reasons for choosing the ported version?**

I would have guessed that I should always prefer the ported version (if available for my jurisdiction), but then I noticed that there are no more ported versions available for the CC 4.0 licenses, and there [don’t seem to](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/CC_Affiliate_Network) be planned any ("Version 4.0 will not be ported absent compelling circumstances"), so using the international version seems to be fine – but does this also apply to version 3.0?

Comment: CC has the FAQ [Should I choose an international license or a ported license?](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Should_I_choose_an_international_license_or_a_ported_license.3F), but it doesn’t go into much detail, and maybe there is more to the decision than the mentioned points.

Answer (score 3):

People used ported versions of Creative Commons licenses because they hoped to take advantage of local legislation that would've supported them in their work. Take this into consideration:

I take a photo, and there's a specific law in Canada that says that my photo is super special, and is bound to receive rights under the federal law. As such, I may choose an appropriate license that allows me to say distribute, while still receiving the benefits of the local legislation. Making use of local legislation was one of the main motivators for choosing a ported license.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you may want to use an international license rather than a ported one is for one reason:

It is globally compatible. This means that anyone (almost anywhere) is subjected to the terms of your license.

Dispite this ported licenses also have their advantages. For example they have been customized and "hand crafted" to specifically work with you local laws. CC says that ported license SHOULD work internationally but in some cases may not.

To read more visit the CC faq page: [here](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Frequently_Asked_Questions%23Should_I_choose_an_international_license_or_a_ported_license.3F)