# Creative Commons: Unported vs. Generic vs. International etc

Tags: licensing, creative-commons

I'm a big user of Creative Common licenses and I often used https://creativecommons.org/choose/ in the past to find the right license to use.

However, I now see many suffixes for `CC Attribution` licenses like:

- CC BY-SA [Unported](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)
- CC BY-SA [International](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)
- CC BY [Generic](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/)

What are the differences?

Also is there a page that shows all CC licenses (including all these tiny variations) on a single page?

I imagine that there will be:

```
CC BY 2.0 Unported
CC BY 2.0 Generic
CC BY 2.0 International
CC BY 3.0 Unported
CC BY 3.0 Generic
CC BY 3.0 International
CC BY 4.0 Unported
CC BY 4.0 Generic
CC BY 4.0 International
CC BY-SA 2.0 Unported
CC BY-SA 2.0 Generic
CC BY-SA 2.0 International
...
```

etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### 4.0

For the latest version of the six main licenses, there are no ports. All of them are ***International***:

- [CC BY 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/)
- [CC BY-NC 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/4.0/)
- [CC BY-ND 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nd/4.0/)
- [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)
- [CC BY-NC-ND 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/)
- [CC BY-NC-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/)

([There might be 4.0 ports in the future](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#what-are-the-international-unported-creative-commons-licenses-and-why-does-cc-offer-ported-licenses): "CC expects that few, if any, ports will be necessary for 4.0.")

#### 3.0 and earlier

For earlier versions, next to the international variant of a license (they are called ***Unported*** in 3.0, and ***Generic*** in earlier versions), there are ports for many jurisdictions.

Examples:

- [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) (Unported)
- [CC BY-SA 3.0 DE](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/de/) (Germany)
- [CC BY-SA 3.0 ES](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/es/) (Spain)
- …
- [CC BY-SA 2.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/) (Generic)
- [CC BY-SA 2.0 DE](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/de/) (Germany)
- [CC BY-SA 2.0 ES](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/es/) (Spain)
- …

(Ports shouldn’t be confused with translations of the human-readable summary page. For example, the summary for the USA port is [also available in German](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/us/deed.de).)

Relevant question: [When to use a ported (instead of an international) CC 3.0 license?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/489/138)

#### List of all licenses

- https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/License_Versions#Licenses links all unported/international licenses
- https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/CC_Ports_by_Jurisdiction mentions all existing ports (unlinked)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By the way "international" is a far better name than "unported" (the negative un- prefix sounds rather anxiogenic).

Comment: What about the Generic version? Is it equivalent to the unported/international versions?

Comment: @waldyrious: Ah, thanks for the notice -- I updated my answer :)